# How to reference value of Excel cell in a sentence written in a different cell? See attached image

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel picture of the problem]

See attached picture. Basically, is there a way to reference B2, i.e. the value 1592 in the comment/sentence written in D2? I don't want to manually write 1592 in D2, but instead would like to reference B2. I of course know how to reference a value from different cell in an empty cell. But when there is text in the cell, I'm lost.
Thank you for any kind of help.

I tried the ordinary way to type =B2 in D2 but it didn't want to reference the cell B2 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### String concatenation:

You can combine text with `=...&...` or the `=CONCAT(..., )`.

For example, in this you could have either

```
="Purchased 2022-12-30: remaining value is "&B2&" out of 1791"
```

*or*

```
=CONCAT("Purchased 2022-12-30: remaining value is ", B2, " out of 1791")
```

If you wanted to make it more dynamic you could put the purchased date and initial value in their own columns, say `E`/`F`, and

```
=CONCAT("Purchased ", E2, ": remaining value is ", B2, " out of ", F2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine string from multiple strings, cell values using `CONCAT`, `CONCATENATE`, `&` or even `TEXTJOIN`

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=CONCATENATE("Purchased 2022-12-30: remaining value is ",B2," out of 1791")
```

?

Result:

[image]